# How can I set socks5 proxy for selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

I really can’t to set socks5 proxy (http too...) for my chrome webdriver in selenium for python.
I tried many different ways... But I think I do something bad.

Example 1:

```
self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://'+proxy)
```

Example 2:

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "socksProxy": proxy,
        "ftpProxy": proxy,
        "sslProxy": proxy,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False
    }
```

Please describe fully the working example of setting up socks5 proxy on Selenium for Python and Chrome webdriver, with an example of proxy string formats (maybe i am doing something mistakes here ...).

PS Two problems which I get:

1. Just staying old IP address.
2. No internet connection in chrome web driver.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Chrome does not allow proxies with authentication.** I am not sure but after reading extensively I think so... I only have one solution currently. I am using a SOCKS5 proxy without authentication by login and password.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = '12.12.421.125:1949'
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

**2023 edit**:

This argument is supported, according to `man chromium`:

> `--proxy-server=host:port`
> Specify  the  HTTP/SOCKS4/SOCKS5 proxy server to use for requests.  This overrides any environment variables or settings picked via the options dialog.

Comment: Can we use prowy auth with chrome nowadays ?

Comment: I just ran a test with Chrome version 116.0.5845.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows and my custom proxy server.  The only authentication method supported by Chrome currently is "NO AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED".

Answer (score 3):

For **FireFox's geckodriver** if you just want to set **socks5 host / socks5 proxy** :-

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# Socks5 Host SetUp:-
myProxy = "198.199.101.152:8388"
ip, port = myProxy.split(':')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', ip)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', int(port))

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used to connect to a Socks5 server with username/password auth.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {
    'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
    'socksProxy': '<Your_IP>:<Your_Port>',
    'socksVersion': 5,
    'ftpProxy': '<Your_IP>:<Your_Port>',
    'noProxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1',
    'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    'autodetect': False
}

capabilities['proxy']['socksUsername'] = '<username>'
capabilities['proxy']['socksPassword'] = '<password>'

driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, is there any update?

Comment: I tried this, in the last line I had to change to "driver = webdriver.Chrome(..." to make it working, but once the browser opened, and tried to go to google.com, I got an error: "ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED"
I was using with my login from NordVPN with this proxy server: atlanta.us.socks.nordhold.net:1080

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me. I googled a lot about setting up socks5 proxy in Chrome. But it's not an easy task for a newbie like me. It's much easier to set up socks5 proxy in Firefox. This code is working for me. But problem is the SSL. I still don't know how to fix that problem. But this code might be helpful to someone like me that's why I'm posting it in here

```
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from seleniumwire import webdriver as sw_webdriver



ip_checker = 'https://whoer.net'
        url = 'https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/password?rapt='
        p_list = random.choice(prox())
        proxy_options = {
            'proxy': {
                'http': f'socks5://{p_list}',
                'https': f'socks5://{p_list}',
                'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'  # add any exceptions here
            }
        }


# CHROME SETTINGS 3
    

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\iron_\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome Beta\User Data")
        options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe"

        # Set proxy options using selenium-wire
        sw_options = {
            'proxy': {
                'http': proxy_options['proxy']['http'],
                'https': proxy_options['proxy']['https'],
                'no_proxy': proxy_options['proxy']['no_proxy'],
            }
        }

    

# Create the Chrome web driver with the specified options and proxy settings
        driver = sw_webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),
            options=options,
            seleniumwire_options=sw_options
        )
        driver.get(ip_checker)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Firefox's geckodriver** , based on [the answer by Tanmay Harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700370/2045384), I have got this so far:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions

proxy = ('proxy-server.local', 1080)

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', proxy[0])
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', proxy[1])
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', True)
driver = Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution tested for version from 2023 with IPv6 proxy (no selenium-wire needed) CHROME:

```
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.set_capability('acceptInsecureCerts', True)

host = "xx"
port = "xx"
socks5User = "xx"
socks5Pass = "xx"
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + host + ":" + port)
options.add_argument("--proxy-auth=" + socks5User + ":" + socks5Pass)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'https': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

source - https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#socks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).